# How to structure React Native navigation for property passing with Typescript

Tags: typescript, react-native, react-navigation

I have a simple React Native app I'm putting together using Typescript and I'm trying to understand how to make the navigation work correctly.

I a list of content sections and when one is selected to open the chosen article in a webview. What I can't grasp is how I am supposed to pass the URL for the webview to load to the view that contains it. Both the navigation list and the web view should fill the screen when they are selected.

As things stand my base component is `GuidanceNavigation` which contains a `Stack.Navigator` with a `Stack.Screen` for the `NavigationItems` view that lists all the topics and a `Stack.Screen` for the `InstructionView` that contains the webview to show the instructions.

As things stand these are all `React.Component` types and the part I am not clear on is that when I am in the `NavigationItems` view I select an option and I need the parent view to replace the `NavigationItems` view with `InstructionView`, providing the `InstructionView` with the title and file location for the selected article. As far as I can tell React Navigation does some magic involving passing in some navigation properties, but I can't figure out how that is supposed to work in a Typescript context or how I can pass my typed objects through the Stack Navigator or even whether the Stack Navigator is the correct component to use in this situation. The [Typescript-specific documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/typescript/) talks about passing through navigation properties but doesn't explain how this is related to the `navigator` object that seems to be available in JavaScript to actually perform navigation.

My code looks like this, it's a while since I have worked with React and my first time using react-native so it's probably neither excellent nor idiomatic:

GuidanceNavigation.tsx:

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export class GuidanceNavigation extends React.Component<{}, {}>  {

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container} >
        <NavigationContainer>
          <Stack.Navigator>
            <Stack.Screen name="Choose a topic" component="NavigationItems" />
            <Stack.Screen name="Instructions" component="InstructionView" />
      </Stack.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  };

}
```

NavigationTypes.ts:

```
export interface IFileLink {
    title: string,
    file: string
}
```

NavigationItems.tsx:

```
import { IFileLink } from './NavigationTypes';

export class NavigationItems extends React.Component<{}, {}>  {

  itemId: number = 0;
  
  readonly items = [
    {
      section: R.strings.menu_steps,
      values: [
    { title: R.strings.menu_getting_started, file: "./assets/html/getting-started.html" },
     // and so on

      ]
    },
    {
      section: R.strings.menu_guidance,
      values: [
    { title: R.strings.menu_glossary, file: "./assets/html/glossary.html" },
        // etc
      ]
    }
  ];

  itemList(itemList: Array<IFileLink>): JSX.Element[] {
    return itemList.map((it) => this.item(it));
  };

  navigateToFile(link:IFileLink) {
    console.log("Navigation to "+link.title);
    // This does not work because navigation comes from ??? somewhere???
    navigation.navigate('Instructions', link);
  };

  item(fileLink:IFileLink): JSX.Element {
    return(
      <Button
    key= { this.itemId++ }
    title= { fileLink.title }
    onPress= {() =>
      this.navigateToFile(fileLink)
    }
      />
    );
  };

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
      <ScrollView>
          <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>{this.items[0].section}</Text>
          {this.itemList(this.items[0].values)}
          <Text style={styles.sectionTitle}>{this.items[1].section}</Text>
          {this.itemList(this.items[1].values)}
      </ScrollView>
    )
  };

}
```

InstructionView.tsx:

```
import { IFileLink } from './NavigationTypes';

export class InstructionView extends React.Component<IFileLink> {

  private fileLink: IFileLink;

  constructor(fl: IFileLink) {
    super(fl);
    this.fileLink = fl;
  }

  render(): JSX.Element {
    return (
        <WebView
          source={{ uri: this.fileLink.file }}
          />
    );
  }
}
```

How can I ensure that I navigate from `NavigationItems` to  `InstructionView` with the required properties when an item is selected in that list?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This does not work because `navigation` comes from ??? somewhere???

The `navigation` object comes from the `props` of the component.  When your component is loaded through `Stack.Screen`, react-navigation calls the component with props `route` and `navigation`.

On the typescript side of things, you need to declare that the `NavigationItems` component **must** be called with this `navigation` prop.  How you do that is what you are seeing explained in the docs.

You declare a `RootStackParamList` type that maps your screen names to their required props.

```
type RootStackParamList = {
    ['Choose a topic']: undefined; // no required props
    Instructions: IFileLink; // requires an IFileLink as props
};
```

You use this type as the generic when you create the `Stack` instance.

```
const Stack = createStackNavigator<RootStackParamList>();
```

You use this type again as the generic when you declare the type of the `navigation` prop for the `NavigationItems` component. Now your component know knows that it will have a prop `navigate`, so you can call `this.props.navigate`.  It also knows very detailed information about where you can navigate to.  The screen name must be either `'Choose a topic'` or `'Instructions'` or else you'll get an error.  It also knows about all of the screens' unique prop requirements, so you now get an error if you try to navigate to `Instructions` without passing an `IFileLink` as the second argument.

```
import { StackNavigationProp, createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';

type ItemsProps = {
    navigation: StackNavigationProp<RootStackParamList, 'Choose a topic'>;
};

export class NavigationItems extends React.Component<ItemsProps, {}>  {

    navigateToFile(link: IFileLink) {
        console.log("Navigation to " + link.title);
        // can now navigate via props
        this.props.navigation.navigate('Instructions', link);
    };

    /*...*/
}
```

There is an error inside your `Navigator`. You need to pass *the components themselves*, not their `string` names.

```
<Stack.Screen name="Choose a topic" component={NavigationItems} />
<Stack.Screen name="Instructions" component={InstructionView} />
```

[Typescript Playground Link](https://tsplay.dev/aNnkBm)